# Need help isolating variables (average translational energy equation)

Tags: gamma-function, rewriting-systems

I need to rewrite  equation so that i can use gamma function. Below are assignment text and my steps and reasoning so far:

The probability of finding a translational energy in the range 
$$E_{tr}, E_{tr} + dE_{tr}$$ is given by: 
$$P(E_{tr})dE_{tr} = 2\cdot \pi \cdot(\frac{1}{\pi \cdot K_{B} \cdot T})^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{E_{tr}} \cdot exp(\frac{-E_{tr}}{K_B\cdot T})dE_{tr}$$

Calculate the average translational energy using equation above

The average value or mean value of a variable x, which can take any value between $-\infty \ and\ \infty$
$$\left\langle x\right\rangle= \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}xP(x)dx$$

So to find the average translational energy:

$$\left\langle E_{tr}\right\rangle= \intop_{0}^{\infty}E_{tr}\cdot P(E_{tr})dx =\intop_{0}^{\infty}E_{tr}\cdot2\cdot \pi \cdot(\frac{1}{\pi \cdot K_{B} \cdot T})^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{E_{tr}} \cdot exp(\frac{-E_{tr}}{K_B\cdot T})dE_{tr}$$

rearranging : 
$$\left\langle E_{tr}\right\rangle=2\cdot \pi \cdot(\frac{1}{\pi \cdot K_{B} \cdot T})^{\frac{3}{2}}\intop_{0}^{\infty}E_{tr}^{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot exp(\frac{-E_{tr}}{K_B\cdot T})dE_{tr}$$

I was given a hint: 
in connection with the evaluation of the integrals the gamma function $\Gamma(n)$ is useful. it is defined as
$$\Gamma(n) = \intop_{0}^{\infty}x^{n-1} \cdot exp(-x)dx, n>0$$

How do I get rid / rearrange the equation so $K_{B}\cdot T$ no longer is in exp() ? I want to get rid of them so the integral will be in the same form as the Gamma $\Gamma(n)$ function.

Thank you for your time reading/helping me with my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from
$$\left\langle E_{tr}\right\rangle=2\cdot \pi \cdot(\frac{1}{\pi \cdot K_{B} \cdot T})^{\frac{3}{2}}\intop_{0}^{\infty}E_{tr}^{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot exp(\frac{-E_{tr}}{K_B\cdot T})dE_{tr}$$

using $y=\frac{E_{tr}}{k_B T}$ in the integration you get

$$\left\langle E_{tr}\right\rangle=\frac{2}{\pi^{1 / 2}} \cdot k_B T\intop_{0}^{\infty}y^{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot exp(-y)dy = \frac{2}{\pi^{1 / 2}} \cdot k_B T \space\ \Gamma(5 / 2)$$

which is reasonable being $k_B T$ an energy

Comment: Thanks you very much ! There is one step I do not follow however:

Using $y=\frac{E_{tr}}{k_B T}$ and then moving $K_B\cdot T$ back in the integral I am left with: 

$$\left\langle E_{tr}\right\rangle=\frac{2}{\pi^{1 / 2}\cdot (K_B \cdot T)^{1/2}} \cdot \intop_{0}^{\infty}y^{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot exp(-y)dy$$

How do can I get from this to what you had ?
Thanks again I really helps me a lot !

Comment: The term $k_B T$ comes out of the sostitution of variable from the differential, while $(k_B T)^{-3/2}$ is regruped with $E_{tr}^{3/2}$ in the integral for the substitution.

Comment: Yes, I see now ! $y=\frac{E_{tr}}{k_B T} $ then $\frac{dy}{dE_{tr}}= \frac{1}{E_{tr}\cdot T}$
Finally $dE_{tr} = K_B \cdot T \cdot dy$